# How to send parameter of a report to another? SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have 3 reports, one general, one synthetic and one graph, they have the same paramentros and each has a link to another, how can I send the parameter chosen in a report and click the link to send the same parameter display the report?

Is this possible?

I am using Report Bulder 3.0 and SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the text box that contains the link, and select textbox properties. Click the "action" tab and select the "Go to Report Action".
Select your report, then add the parameter relationships below that you want to use on the destination report.